# count max value by aggregate function

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I would like to show the number of plans that have at least one named driver so I can work out % of policies with at least 1 driver. There could be 2 drivers for example so I just want to see those who have at least one. This is the code I started and I got stuck on how to make the counts show up as a at least 1 driver for each policy.

```
    SELECT 
case when DRIVER_ROLE = 'Named driver' THEN 1 else null END as named_driver_ind
      ,DD.[DRIVER_ROLE]
      ,PD.[PLAN_NBR]
  FROM DD
  LEFT JOIN PD
  on PD.DRIVE_PLAN_NBR = DD.DRIVE_PLAN_NBR
group by 
DD.DRIVER_ROLE
,DD.[DRIVE_PLAN_NBR]
```

Here's some sample data.. the first 3 rows is one policy with 3 drivers. they have 2 named drivers so it would need to be counted as a yes they have at least 1 driver

```
| DD.driver_role| DD.Drive_Plan_NBR|DP.PLAN_NBR   |DD.Driver_ID | 
|:------------: |:---------------: | :-----------:|:-----------:|
| Named driver  | 756              | 87397        | 123         |
| Policy holder | 756              | 87397        | 124         |
| Named driver  | 756              | 87397        | 125         |
| Policy holder | 759              | 23211        | 188         |
```

Expected outcome is Count of Plan nbr and max count of those with at least 1 driver

```
| count_Plan_nbr| Policies with at least 1 more driver|| 
|:------------: |:------------------------------------:|
| 2             | 1                                    |
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to S/O.  All you really need here is a DISTINCT plan for the condition in question

```
select distinct
      DD.DRIVE_PLAN_NBR
   from
      DD
   where
      DD.Driver_Role = 'Named driver'
```

Start directly with your dd table which has your condition 'Named Driver'.  Since dd also has the plan number, just get distinct which will return ONE regardless of how many.  No group by required.

Now, if you really need the alternate "plan_nbr" vs the ID, just join to pull.  No left required as the primary query will always be pulling those with named drivers anyhow.  You are just getting the extra details

```
select distinct
      DD.DRIVE_PLAN_NBR,
      PD.Plan_Nbr
   from
      DD
         JOIN PD
            on DD.DRIVE_PLAN_NBR = PD.DRIVE_PLAN_NBR
   where
      DD.Driver_Role = 'Named driver'
```

The original query you provided that is showing all the extra parts I THINK were just there to show the context of what you were testing for.  But if your ultimate goal was just which plans had at least one "Named Driver", now you have it.

**FEEDBACK from comment**

Ok, getting closer.  You want how many distinct policies, but also how many actual count of distinct drivers.  So yes, this would use an aggregate but still relatively simple to finish.  I am going to do a two-part and you can use at will.  The first will show each plan and how many drivers

```
select 
      DD.DRIVE_PLAN_NBR,
      PD.Plan_Nbr,
      count(distinct DD.Driver_ID) DriversOnThisPlan
   from
      DD
         JOIN PD
            on DD.DRIVE_PLAN_NBR = PD.DRIVE_PLAN_NBR
   where
      DD.Driver_Role = 'Named driver'
   group by
      DD.DRIVE_PLAN_NBR,
      PD.Plan_Nbr
```

And this would show (From your data), a single row showing the plan number info, but a count # of drivers as 2.  But this query in itself would show every plan and how many drivers per the plan.  To get a single row returned of ALL of this, wrap it up via

```
select 
      count(*) as NumberOfPlansWith1OrMoreDrivers,
      sum( PreQuery.DriversOnThisPlan ) as TotalDriversOnAllPlans
   from
      ( select
              DD.DRIVE_PLAN_NBR,
              PD.Plan_Nbr,
              count(distinct DD.Driver_ID) DriversOnThisPlan
           from
              DD
                 JOIN PD
                    on DD.DRIVE_PLAN_NBR = PD.DRIVE_PLAN_NBR
           where
              DD.Driver_Role = 'Named driver'
           group by
              DD.DRIVE_PLAN_NBR,
              PD.Plan_Nbr ) PreQuery
```

So here, the count(*) just does based on how many unique plans from the inner and the sum() is total drivers across all the plans that qualified.

Now, one caveat, if one driver could be on multiple plans, they would be accounted for under each unique plan which could over-state the actual unique drivers.  For example, I work as a private contractor.  I am one person, but the 5 companies that I work for have a policy with you.  So I am a covered driver for each of those companies.  I would show up on 5 policies, 5 drivers even though I am one person.  Just wanted to explain / clarify a possibility you MAY be asked about, but I think this scenario is a real stretch outlier condition for the normal management concern.

Comment: Hi @drapp Thanks! I'm not sure that will work. The Plan number shows the policy and there can be different driver IDs under that policy. maybe im overthinking this!

Comment: @user16060159, then EDIT your existing post, not via comment.  Add content to the bottom showing some SAMPLE Data, not real policy numbers or names.  Show the proper context as in both tables.  Then show what you want as your final answer.  Show enough SAMPLE data to get the point across on multiple drivers for a single policy / plan / whatever.  That is the best way for myself and others to give a more accurate and complete answer.  When finished, just comment me back you made the changes and I'll look at it again.

Comment: i added more detail

Comment: @user16060159, revised answer.

Comment: @user16060159, if you have an answer that helps or provides good input, it is typical to click the up-arrow on an answer.  If it has SOLVED your issue, use the checkbox next to the answer so others know what did work.